# Using Python with Dialogflow and Facebook Messenger

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to take user input from a facebook messenger interaction with a dialogflow bot and use it in python. This dialogflow bot is a project in google cloud platform. How do I connect these?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code you can add to your question so others can help find any problems? Please read the FAQ on asking questions.

Comment: I'm a beginner in terms of APIs so I guess I need help understanding how to get the API to push data from dialogflow to python

Comment: I Googled ["dialogflow push data python"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=dialogflow+push+data+python&oq=dialogflow+push+data+python) and the top two results give projects others have created to integrate the two.